# How to process 50 million rows fast in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, nlp, spacy

I am trying to measure sentence similarity between 2 sets of questions using Spacy, and then output the pairs along with their similarity score in 3 columns (one dataframe) using pandas.
This will result about 50 million rows, and it has been processing for 12hrs.
Is there any way I can speed up this process please?

user_inputs_vector = [nlp(row) for row in user_inputs_df["User_Input"]] #vectorise user inputs
#creating doc object for comparison
sample_df_vector = [nlp(row) for row in sample_df["Frage"]] #vectorise sample sentences

```
#for loop to compare questions and then append similarity score in empty lists

similarity_score_list = [] 
sample_list = [] 
user_input_list = []

for i in range (len(sample_df_vector)):
    for j in range (len(user_inputs_vector)):    
        similar_frage = user_inputs_vector[j].similarity(sample_df_vector[i])
        similarity_score_list.append(similar_frage)
        sample_list.append(sample_df_vector[i])
        user_input_list.append(user_inputs_vector[j])
        similarity_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(sample_list, user_input_list, similarity_score_list)), columns = ["Samples", "User Inputs", "Similarity Score"])
```

I have run this code in a very small dataframe and it should be ok. It's just that the actual dataset has millions of rows and I don't see it ending yet. Please help.

Comment: It's an `O(n^m)` operation if you do a nested for loop. There's little way around the complexity but there's efficient way to do a dot product and faster similarity library.  How are you getting the similarity score?

Comment: Also if the end product is a retrieval mechanism, then you don't want to get a similarity for every pair of user +data vectors, you would need something like a retrieval system, e.g. nsmlib https://github.com/nmslib/nmslib

Comment: similar_frage = user_inputs_vector[j].similarity(sample_df_vector[i])
similarity_score_list.append(similar_frage)

The lines above are calculating the similarity score, and then appending it in a list. We need to see the similarity score for every pair as that is how my boss wants to see how effective it is.
I don't know how to use nsmlib though....I'm quite a noob to programming in every aspect to be honest...is there any way you could show how to use this function for the problem at hand?
Many thanks for commenting, appreciate it.